# File History - Unable to scan user libraries for changes and perform backup of modified files for configuration

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, backup, file-history

When trying to run the File History tool in Windows 8 it runs for about 2 seconds then stops. No files are backed up to the selected drive.

In the event viewer the only error that appears is event ID #201:

```
Unable to scan user libraries for changes and perform backup of modified files 
for configuration
C:\Users\win8User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\Config
```

or in German

```
Die Benutzerbibliotheken konnten nicht auf Änderungen überprüft werden,
und geänderte Dateien für die Konfiguration 
"C:\Users\win11User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\Config" 
konnten nicht gesichert werden.
```

I've tried deleting both the configuration files and the FileHistory directory on the target drive. Setting up File History again results in the same error.

Is there a better way to track down what is causing the failure? Or somehow get the File History tool to create a more verbose log file that shows what is causing the problem?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the event ID for the problem.

Comment: @User5910 done :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did. I am not sure that all these steps are necessary, but I just wanted to be sure.

1.

`Control panel` -> `File history` -> `Advanced Settings` -> `Open file history event logs` and fix/delete all the files that are messing up file history. For me there were a bunch in this folder:

```
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_explorer.exe xxxxx
```

And I deleted them. They didn't look important.

2 . I wrote a quick python script to find any files with non-ascii characters in their names. I manually renamed all of these. This may be why file history fails on some music folders!

```
import os,string
import sys

validChars='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. #^=!()&,_\'-+@%[]{$};`~'

for currdir,folders,filenames in os.walk(r'C:\Users\<username>'):

    //Max filename len on ntfs is 255, but file history adds "F:\FileHistory\<username>\<computer name>\Data" to the front the files and a timestamp to the end so the file really needs to be less than 200 to be safe
    if len(currdir)>200:
        print 200,currdir

    if filter(lambda x: x in validChars, currdir[2:].replace('\\',''))!=currdir[2:].replace('\\',''):
        print 'chars',currdir,

    for filename in filenames:
        if filter(lambda x: x in validChars, filename)!=filename:
            print 'char2',os.path.join(currdir,filename)
```

EDIT: Don't delete Autodesk Inventor files, it will break autodesk. o_o

3.

File history -> select drive -> (choose your drive) -> (choose your latest backup) -> file history gives some warning about your latest backups not being on this drive. I Clicked OK.

Comment: Same problem for me. As I do not how to run Python scripts (no batch alternative?) I moved all the content one folder after the other to the root of my drive (outside of the library) and after a few minutes the file history works as expected so it hangs on file names or path lengths as you said. The other steps you mentioned were not needed. My file history was empty expect of the error @azl posted in his question. I now will check one subfolder after the other which file caused the problem. Maybe I find out which one caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In saw this error on Windows 10 was caused by a JPEG file with corrupt file attribute flags, in particular a bogus Directory bit. Apparently File History tried to get the children of this non-directory, failed, and silently aborted the entire backup.

File History is grossly negligent in a) reporting errors, and b) handling errors.

### Scanning for problem files

I wrote the following PowerShell function to scan for out-of-range file attributes. Use it as follows:

1. Launch PowerShell
2. Paste in the whole function including the blank line after the last "}"
3. Run it by typing `check-Attributes` and specifying an optional path, ex. `check-Attributes c:\`. If no path is given it will scan starting in the current directory.

```
Function check-Attributes {
    Param([string]$path)

    # Collect all possible attribute bits
    $attrBits = 0
    [enum]::GetValues([System.Io.FileAttributes]) | ForEach-Object {
        $attrBits = $attrBits -bor $_
    }
    $attrBitMask = -bnot $attrBits
    
    Write-Host "Scanning for out-of-range file/directory attributes..."
    $checked = 0
    $out_of_range = 0
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable FailedItems | ForEach-Object {
        ++$checked
        Write-Verbose -Message "Checking $_"
        if (($_.Attributes -band $attrBitMask) -ne 0) {
            Write-Host $_.FullName "has out of range attributes:" $_.Attributes
            ++$out_of_range
        }
    }

    if ($out_of_range) {
        Write-Host
    }
    Write-Host "Checked" $checked "files/directories, found" $out_of_range "with attributes out of range."

    if ($FailedItems) {
        # $FailedItems is an array of System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord
        Write-Host "`nEncountered" $FailedItems.length "error(s) while scanning:"
        $FailedItems | Foreach-Object {$_.CategoryInfo}
    }
}
```

There is no guarantee that testing attributes will find all corruption problems. However because it also reports problems iterating directories it may expose other problems causing File History to fail.

### How I discovered the problem

I used Settings' *Backup options* control to do this. To open it either search Settings for "backup" or click through Settings>System>Storage>View backup options>More options.

The error log may also be helpful. To jump directly to the correct Event Viewer category to see errors, scroll to the bottom of the dialog above, click See advanced settings (this opens Control Panel)>Advanced Settings>Open File History event logs to view recent events or errors. The log path is `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-FileHistory-Engine%4BackupLog.evtx`

The problem file was in one of hundreds of subdirectories in my "Photos" directory. I first created a new parallel directory "Photos-Pending-Backup", excluded it from File History backup, then moved all the directories in "Photos" to it. I ran File History as a sanity check and checked for errors.

**Important**: When checking for success look at the Overview section of Backup options for a new completion time. There is no indication of errors here.

After a successful backup I incrementally moved batches of directories into "Photos" until a backup failed, moved them out until a backup succeeded, repeating until I found the problem.

I decided against excluding all subdirectories from the backup because a) it would take a long time choosing them one at a time using the *Backup options* UI, b) it would be easy to miss one since excluded folders are not shown in sorted order, and c) it would also take a long time to unexclude them.

Comment: Note the search for unusual attributes can produce *false positives*: Files in the OneDrive folder, which are not on the local machine, have attributes (value 4199968 in my case) but don't cause issues with File History. Otherwise, a well-written answer, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the [script posted by apple16 above](https://superuser.com/a/802187) to run in Python 3 and enhanced it a bit.  Using a combination of selectively excluding folders from File History and this script to look at possible issues I narrowed down my problem to two files with nearly identical names in the same directory.  Both files had the word Espanol in the filename with a tilde over the n.  However one had the encoding as:  Espan\N{COMBINING TILDE}ol and the other as Espa\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE}ol.   Both file names listed identically in Windows Explorer with the tilde over the n.  When I put these two files in separate folders they are backed up just fine by File History, but when in the same directory they seem to interfere with each other and block File History operation.

Here's the script CheckFileNames.py I used:

```
#CheckFileNames.py, 10 May 2016, LewisN
#Python 3 version adapted and enhanced by LewisN; based on script by apple16 posted on https://superuser.com/a/802187
#Scans Windows file system for potentially problematic directories and files affecting File History operation.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#SET THE FOLLOWING BEFORE RUNNING:
DirectoryTreeToScan = r'C:\Users\<username>'
DaysBackToList = 0    #Number of days back to list. Set to 0 to list all FLAGGED FILES regardless of file dates.
PrintDates = False    #Set True to show File Creation and Modification dates.

#You may also want to play with the following settings:
flagDirLen=200
flagFullNameLen=200
  # Max filename len on Windows is ~255, but File History adds "F:\FileHistory\<username>\<computer name>\Data" to 
  # the front the files and a timestamp to the end, so backing off on name lengths flagged to be safe.
  # Files with long filenames are actually saved to F:\FileHistory\<username>\<computer name>\Data\$OF and can be
  # retrieved using the File History GUI, but you may want to avoid this.  Also there may be cases where
  # long paths and/or filenames cause errors.

#Notes: 
#  1. Filenames with Unicode characters from various languages are also often ok for File History.  
#     This script exposes these characters so they can be examined for potential problems.
#  2. Filenames with initial dots (also flagged here) are ok for File History (use cmd prompt to edit them).
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import os,string,time,datetime
import sys

validChars="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. #^=!()&,_'-+@%[]{$};`~"
disallowedChars=r'\/:*?"<>|'
# Note that many other characters are also actually allowed.  Windows expressly disallows \/:*?"<>|    

lastdirheader=''

def PrintDirHeaderIfNeeded():
    global lastdirheader
    if currdir!=lastdirheader:
        print ('===FLAGGED FILES IN DIRECTORY',currdir.encode("ascii","replace").decode()+':')
        lastdirheader = currdir
        return;
        
def PrintFileDates():
    fname=os.path.join(currdir,filename)
    print('      Created: ' + time.ctime(os.path.getctime(fname)) + ', Modified: ' + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(fname)))
    return;

def IsRecent(DaysBack):
    fname=os.path.join(currdir,filename)
    if DaysBack==0: return True   # 0 disables limiting file listings based on file dates
    if ((datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(fname))).days<DaysBack) or \
       ((datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fname))).days<DaysBack):
        return True 
    else: return False;

for currdir,folders,filenames in os.walk(DirectoryTreeToScan):
   
    if len(currdir)>flagDirLen:
        print('===DIRLEN>' + str(flagDirLen) + ':', currdir.encode("ascii","replace").decode())
   
    if ''.join([x for x in currdir[2:].replace('\\','') if x in validChars])!=currdir[2:].replace('\\',''):
        print('===DIR CHARS+:',currdir.encode("ascii","namereplace").decode())
   
    for filename in filenames:
            
        if (len(currdir)+len(filename)>flagFullNameLen) and IsRecent(DaysBackToList):
            PrintDirHeaderIfNeeded()
            print('     FULLNAMELEN>' + str(flagFullNameLen) + ':', filename.encode("ascii","replace").decode())
            if PrintDates: PrintFileDates() 
    
        if ''.join([x for x in filename if x in validChars])!=filename and IsRecent(DaysBackToList):
            PrintDirHeaderIfNeeded()
            print('     CHARS+:',filename.encode("ascii","namereplace").decode())
            if PrintDates: PrintFileDates() 
            
        if filename[0:1] == "." and IsRecent(DaysBackToList):
            PrintDirHeaderIfNeeded()
            print('     INITIAL DOT:',filename.encode("ascii","replace").decode())
            if PrintDates: PrintFileDates()
            
        if any(True for x in filename if x in disallowedChars) and IsRecent(DaysBackToList):
            PrintDirHeaderIfNeeded()
            print('     DISALLOWED (' + disallowedChars + '):',filename.encode("ascii","replace").decode())
            if PrintDates: PrintFileDates()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this exact File History defect. It tooks me 10 days to understand that my FH setup was stuck and found no way to understand what may be wrong:

- I tried to use attributes investigation script available here in other answers
- I have created a list of files with modification dates (I should have dumped creation dates IMO)
- I look for EBD files content for a clue for latest files included in backup with NirSoft ESE Database View (do not, it leads to nothing)
- I tried a lot of actions found anywhere to get it run again, but most instructions are useless and articles often concluded by proposing another (often commercial) backup tool

Before doing tests, it is worth to keep an initial copy of "Configuration" folder of your target storage. You may discard local "Configuration" folder in AppData and replace it by content from target storage without harm as far as backup is disabled and service is stopped. You can retrieve your initial situation with complete history copying these files back to their location.

I have applied the following diagnostic method to identify what files do not suit FH service:

- open Process Explorer to find "svchost.exe" process ID with "fhsvc" parameter, when backup is running its "working set" is larger than any other "svchost.exe" processes
- open Process Monitor and configure

  - filter to only include "svchost.exe" process name and identified PID for fhsvc service
  - enable ring buffer with 100 MiB limit in Options / History Depth (or else collected events fill virtual memory and Windows starts to kill applications)
  - check "Drop Filtered Events" in Filter menu
  - enable Capture, Autoscroll and keep only "Show File System Activity" button enabled
  - with these options, you should avoid crashes, which happens soon when visible collected events timestamp do shift many minutes behind your clock
- waits for File History backup to fail (in my situation, from 25 to 40 minutes depending on "Excluded folders")

With this inspection tooling, here is what I deducted about File History service behavior:

- it first scans file system for files to include in next backup
- if scan processus failed, you will only find one generic failure in Event Viewer
- only if full scan has succeeded
- for each file, it updates backup catalog in local EDB files `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\Catalog1.edb` and copy file as backup on target storage
- when over, it copies `Catalog1.edb` as `Catalog2.edb` probably to keep a backup in case of write corruption if interrupted during previous process
- it copies the local EDB `Catalog1.edb` also to target storage as `Catalog2.edb` (my hypothesis is that `Catalog1.edb` is created only at first backup)

How I have identified files in trouble for File History service:

- looking back in latests Process Monitor file events before failure
- I saw ".dotnet" and ".android" in my home folder and then remembered it was at that time I have setup Android "repo" command in my WSL Debian to build an Android image
- so I deleted both ".dotnet/" and ".android/" folders I no longer care about, even if they would have been useful for further investigation (anyway I have spent already too much time on this topic)

After moving files in trouble out of FH path (another option may be to exclude folder for instance) and waiting for a complete successful backup, I have retrieved my complete FH history with previous snapshots in "Restore" interface because I have restored the original "Configuration" content after my diagnostic tests.

Backup process is now back to order but I still do not know what king of troubles these files have to prevent File History to handle them.

**Update** I got other troubles later, and my hypothesis is now FH gets stuck with files hold open by a running process which frequently updates its content. In my specific case, Grindstone and its database. As a work-around, I stop Grindstone and FH successfully proceeds its backup.

Answer (score 0):

**To the OPs questions:** I don't think there is a good way to track down these types of issues, and I haven't found a way to increase the logging to a useful level.

If you want to try fixing it for your own case, **read all the answers here**, they complement each other well!

**My 2 cents:** Building on [another answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1075326/72707), I have worked on a script to **actively rename files** that contain characters that could cause a problem, since in my case source of the issue was spread across 4 directories with ~10 GB data. The following script renames "weird" characters to "more normal ones", while accepting many that I have experimentally found not to cause issues. Maybe it can solve the problem for you. Note that if you also have some folders that need renaming, you need to modify the code slightly.

```
#CheckFileNames.py, 2024-01-05, JonasHeidelberg 
#Python 3 version adapted and enhanced by JonasHeidelberg
# Based on script by LewisN from https://superuser.com/a/1075326/72707 which in turn was 
# based on script by apple16 posted on https://superuser.com/a/802187/72707
#Scans Windows file system for potentially problematic directories and files affecting File History operation.
#Then tries to rename some of thos those files, if "RenameCount is set>0"
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#SET THE FOLLOWING BEFORE RUNNING:
DirectoryTreeToScan = r'C:\\Users\\Username\\' 

DaysBackToList = 0    #Number of days back to list. Set to 0 to list all FLAGGED FILES regardless of file dates.
PrintDates = False    #Set True to show File Creation and Modification dates.

#You may also want to play with the following settings:
RenameCount = 0 # For testing purposes - limits how many files are being renamed. Set to 0 to avoid any renaming. Can probably set to float('inf') for no limit
flagDirLen=200
flagFullNameLen=200
  # Max filename len on Windows is ~255, but File History adds "F:\FileHistory\<username>\<computer name>\Data" to 
  # the front the files and a timestamp to the end, so backing off on name lengths flagged to be safe, e.g. 200.
  # Files with long filenames are actually saved to F:\FileHistory\<username>\<computer name>\Data\$OF and can be
  # retrieved using the File History GUI, but you may want to avoid this.  Also there may be cases where
  # long paths and/or filenames cause errors.

#Notes: 
#  1. Filenames with Unicode characters from various languages are also often ok for File History.  
#     This script exposes these characters so they can be examined for potential problems.
#  2. Filenames with initial dots (also flagged here) are ok for File History (use cmd prompt to edit them).
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import os,string,time,datetime
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

validChars="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. #^=!()&,_'-+@%[]{$};`~öäüöäüäÖÄÜß§–é´¨„“€ŽÂÉóδñ�" 
# Note: äöü appear 2-3 times, but differently encoded!
# Note that many other characters are also actually allowed.  Windows expressly disallows \/:*?"<>|    
validCharsSet = set(validChars)
outsideValidChars = defaultdict(int)
disallowedChars=r'\/:*?"<>|'
replacement_table = {
    '\\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE}\\N{VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER}': 'ü',
    '\\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE}\\N{CURRENCY SIGN}': 'ä',
    'aI\\N{COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT}\\x88': 'ä',
    'u\\N{BROKEN BAR}\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX}': 'ü',
    'U\\N{BROKEN BAR}\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX}': 'Ü',
    '\\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE}\\x83\\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX}\x9c': 'Ü',
    'A\\x83\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX}\\x9c': 'Ü',
    'A\\x9c': 'Ü',
    '\\N{HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS}': '...',
    '\\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}': '',
    '\\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}': '',
    '\\N{RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}': "'",
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX}': 'e',
    '\\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE}': 'A',
    '\\N{MIDDLE DOT}': '.',
    '\\N{BULLET}': '.',
    '\\N{LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK}': '',
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I}': 'i',
    '\\N{EM DASH}': '-',
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE}': 'i',
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA}': 'c',
    '\\N{SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK}': "'",
    '\\N{SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK}': "'",
    '\\N{SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK}': "'",
    '\\N{LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}': "'",
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE}': 'u',
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH MACRON}': 'o',
    '\\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE}': 'D',
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE}': 'd',
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE}': 'c',
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE}': 'e',
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE}': 'a',
    '\\N{SOFT HYPHEN}': '-',
    '\\N{LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE}': 'oe',
    '\\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX}': 'E'
}
lastdirheader=''

def PrintDirHeaderIfNeeded():
    global lastdirheader
    if currdir!=lastdirheader:
        print ('===FLAGGED FILES IN DIRECTORY',currdir.encode("ascii","replace").decode()+':')
        lastdirheader = currdir
        return;

def PrintFileDates():
    fname=os.path.join(currdir,filename)
    print('      Created: ' + time.ctime(os.path.getctime(fname)) + ', Modified: ' + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(fname)))
    return;

def IsRecent(DaysBack):
    fname=os.path.join(currdir,filename)
    if DaysBack==0: return True   # 0 disables limiting file listings based on file dates
    if ((datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(fname))).days<DaysBack) or \
       ((datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fname))).days<DaysBack):
        return True 
    else: return False;


def replace_unicode_in_filename(directory, filename ):
    new_filename = filename
    
    # Go through all patterns to replace critical elements in filename
    for unicode_pattern, replacement in replacement_table.items():
        new_filename = new_filename.replace(unicode_pattern.encode().decode('unicode-escape'), replacement)
    
    print(filename.encode("ascii","namereplace").decode() + "-->" + new_filename + ": ", end="")
    print(os.rename(os.path.join(directory, filename), os.path.join(directory, new_filename)))
    
    return

print('Scanning ' + DirectoryTreeToScan + '...')
for currdir,folders,filenames in os.walk(DirectoryTreeToScan):

    if len(currdir)>flagDirLen:
        print('===DIRLEN>' + str(flagDirLen) + ':', currdir.encode("ascii","replace").decode())

    mod_currdir = currdir[2:].replace('\\', '')
    if ''.join([x for x in mod_currdir if x in validChars])!=mod_currdir:
        print('===DIR CHARS+:',currdir.encode("ascii","namereplace").decode())
        for char in mod_currdir:
            if char not in validCharsSet:
                outsideValidChars[char] += 1            

    for filename in filenames:

        if (len(currdir)+len(filename)>flagFullNameLen) and IsRecent(DaysBackToList):
            PrintDirHeaderIfNeeded()
            print('     FULLNAMELEN>' + str(flagFullNameLen) + ':', filename.encode("ascii","replace").decode())
            if PrintDates: PrintFileDates() 

        if any(True for x in filename if x in disallowedChars) and IsRecent(DaysBackToList):
            PrintDirHeaderIfNeeded()
            print('     DISALLOWED (' + disallowedChars + '):',filename.encode("ascii","replace").decode())
            if PrintDates: PrintFileDates()

        if ''.join([x for x in filename if x in validChars])!=filename and IsRecent(DaysBackToList):
            PrintDirHeaderIfNeeded()
            print('     CHARS+:',filename.encode("ascii","namereplace").decode())
            if PrintDates: PrintFileDates() 
            for char in filename:
                if char not in validCharsSet:
                    outsideValidChars[char] += 1
            if RenameCount > 0:
                replace_unicode_in_filename(currdir,filename)
                RenameCount = RenameCount - 1
    # HERE you would rename directories if needed -- NOT IMPLEMENTED YET!
    
# Now sort & print outsideValidChars:
sorted_chars = sorted(outsideValidChars.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

print("Overview of the unusual characters found, by occurence:")

print("Character | Occurence")
print("---------------------")
for char, count in sorted_chars:
    readable_char = char.encode("ascii", "namereplace").decode()
    print(f"{readable_char} | {count}")
```