# Windows 10 File History is silently refusing to back up some of my files

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, file-history

I happened to check on my backups and I noticed that certain files are missing, even though I have them included in the backup. Good thing I checked! So how do I get them included in the backup? It's weird because I have this one directory that is only partially included - some of the files are there and others are not...

I thought the problem was that my backup drive was out of space, so I deleted and excluded some files that are already synced online and consuming lots of space (e.g. Google Drive) but still the backup fails to include certain files of mine...

Could it have anything to do with the fact that I have a junction point pointing at this folder? The folder is C:\Users\edkol\source\repos, and I have a junction point at C:\Users\edkol\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects pointing there.

Comment: I would recommend a more robust backup solution than File History.

Comment: Directory junctions backup without issue, so this isn't the cause.  Your issue requires far more information to troubleshoot, but I would recommend checking the event viewer for the cause of the issue.  I've never had an issue with File History not backing up all files in a directory and I've been utilizing it for ~4yrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wound up doing is deleting my backups off of the backup drive, then excluding a few folders that are already backed up to cloud services (e.g. Google Drive), and running the backup from scratch. The size of the backup went down from 890GB to 80GB and all my files were backed up.

Answer (score 1):

if the filename is to long, (more than about 145 caracters, including the folders name), the file will be backed up in the $OF subfolder instead of the actual copy of the same folder hierachy in the filehistory folder.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNsID.png)
But if you click on "file history" in the actual folder, you will see that it is acually included in the file history.  Maybe it is your case (it was for me).  Also, empty folders are not included in the file history backup.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that File History gets stuck with some particular file attributes when scanning for elements to include in backup. Please refer to [File History - Unable to scan user libraries for changes and perform backup of modified files for configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/550761/file-history-unable-to-scan-user-libraries-for-changes-and-perform-backup-of-m) for diagnostic means.